# As Xaml is vector based, do large shapes use more memory?

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector

As the title suggests, i am interested in know if a large shape takes up more memory in a WPF application or is it all algorithm based and it doesnt really matter?

Cheers, Kohan

---

Addendum, The reason i ask is i would like a visual curved header at the top of my page. I have done this using a very large ellipse that is positioned at the top of the page, most of it goes off the page and i am only viewing a little of it, but it gives the desired visual effect. (Hope this makes sense)

I was just wondering if it was really inefficient to have this huge elipse on the screen and was instead considering creating a custom path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Rune Andersen said, it depends.

But if you redraw all the content of your window very often, like if you pan and zoom, it may be very slow using vector because he needs to recalculate every vector each time.

**Edit:**

You should always convert your Ellipse to a Path. Our team did many performance test and Ellipse are probably the worst one. In Blend, you right click on the Ellipse and you have the option: Convert to Path. If you want just post the Ellipse and I'll give you the Path.

Comment: Regarding the ellipse, that is probably because it uses sine and cosine, where path is linear. If you need to zoom in on a path-based ellipse it will have edges - unless it is a bezier path approximation.

Comment: Cool, many thanks for the information i'll give that a go. and you are right it was jagged at the edges.

Answer (score 1):

I think
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics

more or less sums up the advantages and drawbacks of using a vectorbased representation vs bitmap.

Graphics represented as vectors can be scaled and is often the most compact representation.

If you vectorize an image using some imageprocessing you end up with a lot of vectors, some of them may only represent a single pixel - you can get a very large vector representation.

However the memory requirement of a shape is dependant of its complexity not the size in pixels.

So if you scale a complex shape to icon size and never display it bigger you are better off using a bitmap format.